# how to recognise "wrong" pointers

Tags: c++, mfc, dump, pykd

I'm working with heap_stat, a script, based on PYKD library (the script performs `Ptrptr()` on `!heap -h 0` results and continues from there).

This heap_stat script sometimes contains wrong results, as you can see from following excerpt:

**heap_stat source code:**

```
if (type_name.endswith("CStringArray") or
    ... :
    if type_name.endswith("CStringArray"):
        collection_Size = typedVar('CStringArray', ptr).m_nSize
    elif 
    ...
    try:
        dprintln(("0x" + pointer_format + "\t%s\t Size:[%d]") % (ptr, type_name, collection_Size))
```

**Results excerpts:**

```
...
0x000002660b40d890      mfc140u!CStringArray     Size:[9],
...
0x000002660ae8c6d0      mfc140u!CStringArray     Size:[8589934592]
...
```

**Verifying this in Visual Studio yields following results:**

```
-    (CStringArray*)0x000002660b40d890    0x000002660b40d890 {size = 9, pointer : 0x000002660b40d890}
    [size]      9    __int64
    [capacity]  9    __int64
    [grow by]   0    __int64
+    [0]    L""    mfc140u.dll!ATL::CStringT<wchar_t,StrTraitMFC_DLL<wchar_t,ATL::ChTraitsCRT<wchar_t> > >
+    [1]    L""    mfc140u.dll!ATL::CStringT<wchar_t,StrTraitMFC_DLL<wchar_t,ATL::ChTraitsCRT<wchar_t> > >
+    [2]    L""    mfc140u.dll!ATL::CStringT<wchar_t,StrTraitMFC_DLL<wchar_t,ATL::ChTraitsCRT<wchar_t> > >
+    [3]    L""    mfc140u.dll!ATL::CStringT<wchar_t,StrTraitMFC_DLL<wchar_t,ATL::ChTraitsCRT<wchar_t> > >
+    [4]    L""    mfc140u.dll!ATL::CStringT<wchar_t,StrTraitMFC_DLL<wchar_t,ATL::ChTraitsCRT<wchar_t> > >
+    [5]    L""    mfc140u.dll!ATL::CStringT<wchar_t,StrTraitMFC_DLL<wchar_t,ATL::ChTraitsCRT<wchar_t> > >
+    [6]    L""    mfc140u.dll!ATL::CStringT<wchar_t,StrTraitMFC_DLL<wchar_t,ATL::ChTraitsCRT<wchar_t> > >
+    [7]    L""    mfc140u.dll!ATL::CStringT<wchar_t,StrTraitMFC_DLL<wchar_t,ATL::ChTraitsCRT<wchar_t> > >
+    [8]    L""    mfc140u.dll!ATL::CStringT<wchar_t,StrTraitMFC_DLL<wchar_t,ATL::ChTraitsCRT<wchar_t> > >
```

=> Correct

```
-    (CStringArray*)0x000002660ae8c6d0    0x000002660ae8c6d0 {size = 8589934592, pointer : 0x000002660ae8c6d0}
    [size]      8589934592    __int64
    [capacity]  8589934594    __int64
    [grow by]   8589934594    __int64
+    [Raw View]    0x000002660ae8c6d0 {m_pData=0x88000000bb1d05ba ??? m_nSize=8589934592 m_nMaxSize=8589934594 ...}
```

=> Wrong: this seems to be a leftover of an object which is not valid anymore.

My question: is there any feature in PYKD to filter out those wrong objects? Is there even a way to recognise those while debugging in Visual Studio? And not to forget: what are those leftovers? I don't think there's much `delete array_with_strings` where `array_with_strings` is a CStringArray in my source code.

Comment: Those 'leftovers' look like sentinel values. The decimal value `8589934592` is `0x2'0000'0000` in hex, which doesn't look like a reasonable size value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In response to IInspectable's comment: that was a real coincidence, having exactly that number. But it put me thinking: are there any limitations to that number, and in fact, it's very simple:

The size of a `CStringArray` (or any other `MFC` collection for that matter) is an `int`, which means that it is bounded by `INT_MAX` (being `2^21-1`).

So, I've adapted my heap_stat script, filtering out all `MFC` objects, having a size, larger than `2^21-1`.

Comment: `INT_MAX` is `2^32-1` or `0xFFFF'FFFF`. Do you really have this many strings in memory?

Comment: @BarmakShemirani: according to "https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-language/cpp-integer-limits?view=vs-2019", INT_MAX is 2^21-1, not 2^32-1. I surely don't have this amount of entries in memory, but I didn't have a maximum value I could check on.

Comment: Okay, we are both wrong. `INT_MAX` is `2^31 - 1` or `0x7FFF'FFFF`. By the way, `8589934592` is 64-bit integer. I am not sure how you end up with that value. Make sure the index is `>= 0` and less than `m_stringarray.GetCount()`